# Trying to get value from a select field, which I filled with an SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I come to you in dire need.

What I'm trying to do is to make a form with a dropdown menu, that menu is filled by fetching id's from a table.

```
<form method="post" action="addWorkExperience.php">

<select name="employerSelection">
            <?php
            $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT employer_id FROM employers");
            while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<option value=\"eID\"> " .$row['employer_id']  . "</option>";
            }
            ?>    
</select>
```

And to my understanding my selected option should be accessible through the $_POST variable like so:

```
$eValue = $_POST['employerselection'];
```

or:

```
$sValue = $_POST['eID'];
```

These variables would be used in my insert query to write my choice back to the SQL database. However, for some reason it just doesn't. Every other inputfield I trow at it works, except the select field.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, instead of

```
$eValue = $_POST['employerselection'];
```

try

```
$eValue = $_POST['employerSelection'];
```

In further situations, you can help yourself by simply using

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

that will output all variables that `$_POST` contains

Comment: Just checked, it's not the typo. The typo here is from translating quickly.

I'll give the var_dump a try;

Comment: I have no idea what `translating` means - but in case it means that this is not your original code - you should really post your original code so we are able to help you.

Comment: Well i'm using Dutch words (not translating the actual code).
I've used the var_dump and it tells me that it's trying to pass employerSelection as "eID". Which the database rejects because it's going to an INT field.

Comment: @Jaqen Yea because thats what you defined as option value. You'd need to do `<option value='" . $row['employer_id'] . "'...`

Comment: I'm such an idiot. I'll give it a shot first thing in the morning. Thanks for helping me!